# Reference to other object as reference class field

Tags: c++, r, class, oop

I come from a C++ background and I'm trying to learn R. When I wanted an object to keep track of another already existing object using C++ classes, I would just add a pointer member. I know R does not support pointers by default, but I need to add that functionality to my reference classes.

In C++ I would do something like

```
class foo
{
public:
    foo *pAnotherFoo;
}
```

If I try to do something like
`foo <- setRefClass( "foo", fields = list(another = "foo") )`
I obviously get `Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion....`, as R tries to instantiate the object, that will instantiate another one and so on (I think?).

I wonder if there is some way to tell R that I don't want that field to get instantiated and I will assign a value to it later.

Comment: C does not have classes.

Comment: Could you possibly demonstrate what you are trying to do with a (small) example in C?

Comment: this does not seem to be about C programming (maybe about C++ programming) suggest removing the 'c' tag

Comment: @WeatherVane, You are right, sorry. I was used to just say C instead of C++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you are using reference classes in R. If so, you can simply define

```
foo <- setRefClass('foo', 
       fields = list(anotherObject = 'ANY'))
```

As I'm sure you can guess, this does **not** enforce that `anotherObject` is of class `foo`, but there's no reason you cannot set this value to be an object of class `foo`. In fact, doing so will speed up performance (otherwise, your object will check the class of anotherObject *every* time your object is altered). So your desired reference behavior (without class enforcement) could be implemented by

```
myObj1 <- new('foo')
myObj2 <- new('foo')
myObj1$anotherObject <- myObj2
```

To illustrate the reference behavior, consider

```
myObj1$anotherObject$anotherObject <- 1
myObj2$anotherObject
[1] 2
```